# How to obtain the function name and number of arguments from a function in C?

Tags: c, api, dynamic, function-pointers, dispatch

Lets say I am maintaining an array of function structures in which I store API information.

This is definition of function structure:

```
typedef struct function {
    void (*func)(long, ...);
    char* name;
    int argc;
    char *argv[];
} function;

function api_list[N]
```

I would maintain a list of such structures.
Now given any function, I want to write a function **Register(api_list, fp)**
which adds one such structure initialized with details of function fp.

```
int fp(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}

Register(api_list, fp);
```

How to do it in C?

Comment: and FYI, your function signatures doesn't match, as it looks currently.

Comment: If you make `Register` a preprocessor macro that wraps the actual register function, it's easy to get the function name. I'm not so sure about the other fields, what are `argc`  and `argv` supposed to be fore?

Comment: AFAIK C does not have native introspection support. There may be an easier way but if you want a generic solution that can handle any function at runtime then the only way I know of is to examine the DWARF debugging info for the built objects.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg argc is the no. of arguments, I know the macro _FUNCTION_, likewise is there any macro to get no of arguments and argv is argument string.

Comment: @SouravGhosh that is intentional, long can be downcasted to anything. That first argument can be a pointer as well, as generic as well

Comment: `long` can't be casted to anything. There no guarantee that `long` is the largest signed integer type, only that it's *at least* as large as `int`. For example, using the Visual Studio compiler in Windows, `long` is still 32 bits even on 64-bit systems.

Comment: And no, there's no standard way of getting the arguments types or number of arguments from a function. The compiler *might* have some extensions for it, but I doubt it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. just checked out this one.. actually I want to implement this in a project and was just writing toy prototypes to check if its actually possible in C.   BTW what about getting the function name and arguments.. Is it possible.. Any amount of hackery is acceptable.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  ok. Let me tell you the overall purpose. of this.. I am writing a test library for APIs. To call APIs in any random order through remote connection. I wanted to automate the process for initializing api_list.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  So basically I pass a string over network containg <function_name><space><arg1><space><arg2>.... so on. On remote end I maintain an array of structures which has all available APIs to be called. I tokenize stuff, search for the name in function list and call it. I pass the return value back over the network

Comment: Like I said, there's no standard way (and likely no non-standard way either) to get the argument types and count of any function. All you can hope for is that the client sends the correct number of arguments for the specified function. If you need an argument count you need to enter it manually.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This is an embedded platform, so C++ can't be used here. Nor can I use RPC because lot of porting has to be done. I have to use C99.

Comment: Doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks I got your point. I am asking if there any alternative way to realize this behavior... I have intermediate knowledge of C, so just wanted to validate my approach.. I have my own implementation but I feel an optimized way of doing it is possible

Comment: I saw a library for doing this a while back when I was scanning through a list of RPMs on a Linux system. I can't remember the name but it implemented the ABI to call C functions with dynamic numbers and types of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will need to either parse the C function declarations yourself or find some other code to do it. I looked around a bit and there's code for this in the Ruby FFI, PerlXS and other script binding generators like SWIG. I also saw the XML plugin to GCC which generates XML describing the program.

If you look up C's BNF or EBNF definitions and know a bit of parsing theory, figuring out C functions is not hard. C++ is a whole other ball o' wax.

Note: I think I misunderstood. The following is for *calling* C functions with unknown number and types of arguments. Not for finding out what the function signature already looks like.

Look at the FFI (Foreign Function Interface) library which can be found at Sourceware:
https://sourceware.org/libffi/

This is packaged with many Linux systems already because it is heavily used by interpreted languages that need to call C functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Now given any function, I want to write a function `Register(api_list, fp)` which adds one such structure initialized with details of function fp.

There is no way to do this in Standard C. The main reason is you need keep track of original definition of an function to call it via such structure. You actually *could* store every function pointer as struct member:

```
void (*func)()
```

that is fine, but any attempt to call such function when type is **not compatible** (both parameters and return type are not the same) with original definition will invoke *undefined behaviour*. This means, that you would need to cast it properly for every call:

```
((int (*)(int, int)) api_list[0])(1, 2);
```

You may use GCC extensions [`typeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html#Typeof), but this method requires writing function's name (here `fp`) explicitely:

```
int result = ( (typeof(fp)*) api_list[0].func)(1, 2);
```

Even if you have stored somehow character string `"fp"` inside `name` member, there is no way to "connect" it with `typeof`, since it does not take string literals (well it takes, but not in the way you want) and in general there is no way to have it "destringized" as `fp` token.

Here is an illustration of above concepts:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*GENERIC_FUNC_PTR)();

typedef struct function
{
    GENERIC_FUNC_PTR func;
} function;

void Register(function *api_list, GENERIC_FUNC_PTR func)
{
    api_list->func = func;
}

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

void print_message(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", __func__); 
}

int main(void)
{
    function api_list[10];
    Register(api_list, (GENERIC_FUNC_PTR) add);
    Register(api_list + 1, (GENERIC_FUNC_PTR) print_message);

    printf("%d\n", ( (typeof(add)*) api_list[0].func)(1, 2));
    ( (typeof(print_message)*) api_list[1].func)();

    return 0;
}
```